# How to add element in static list of type object

Tags: java

How to add element in static list of type object.

I have List of Object like this.

```
List<Object[]> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

How can I add static element in that ?

Suppose my element is like

```
[{
    name : "David",
    roll : "1234",
    class : 5
}]
```

What I am trying is

```
static List<Object[]> myList = new ArrayList<>();

myList.add([{
    name : "David",
    roll : "1234",
    class : 5
}])
```

but this is failing.

Comment: Looking at the question I was thinking that this was asked by a new user but was surprised to see your reputation @David. If you can accept the data as a JSON I suggest you create a custom class with attributes such as `name`, `roll`, and `class`, then you can try to convert that JSON array (input) into a list of your custom class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write a separate class of that:

For example:

```
public class User {
  private final String name;
  private final String roll;
  private final int uClass;

  public User(String name, String roll, int uClass) {
    this.name = name;
    this.roll = roll;
    this.uClass = uClass;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public String getRoll() {
    return roll;
  }

  public int getuClass() {
    return uClass;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
      "name='" + name + '\'' +
      ", roll='" + roll + '\'' +
      ", uClass=" + uClass +
      '}';
  }
}
```

And then in different classes, you can use it as:

```
private final ArrayList<User> users= new ArrayList<>();
```

To add a new User object:

```
User user1 = new User("David", "1234", 5);
users.add(user1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[{
    name : "David",
    roll : "1234",
    class : 5
}]
```

This is not a Java object -- not even a Java object array.

You could add a Java object array, of course.

```
myList.add(new Object[] {"David", "1234", 5});
```

...but that's not the object you're looking for.  It sounds like you need a class.

Comment: I am writing the testacases. thats why thinking do i need a class or without class also I can do that.

Comment: You _always_ need a class in Java.

Comment: ya Noted. Thanks/